# Can someone explain this particular use of the replace() method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript and came across a practice problem on the web that I was able to solve but didn't match the given solution which was much more compact. The follow code just takes a word, reverses the letters and then replaces a, e, o , u with numbers. I did a lot of research but can't seem to understand how the following arrow function parameter of the replace() method works:

```
    match => replaceChars[match]
```

Here is the complete code:

```
    var x = "orange";
    var y = x.split("").reverse().join("");
    var replaceChars={ "a": 0 , "e": 6, "o": 2, "u": 9 };
    var t = y.replace(/[aeou]/g,match => replaceChars[match]);
    console.log(t)
```

Edit: Thanks for the quick answers. I get it now. I just needed to write it out like this to fully understand:

```
    var x = "orange";
    var y = x.split("").reverse().join("");
    var replaceChars={ "a": 0 , "e": 6, "o": 2, "u": 9 };
    function matchFunc(match){
    x = replaceChars[match];
    return x;}
    console.log (replaceChars["a"])
    var t = y.replace(/[aeou]/g,matchFunc);
    console.log(t)
```

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace): *"A function to be invoked to create the new substring to be used to replace the matches..."*  Are you familiar with [arrow syntax for functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)?

Comment: `matchFunc` is a horrible parameter name. It should be just `match`. You might want to try `(match) => { console.log(match, replaceChars[match]); return replaceChars[match]; }` to understand what's happening.

Comment: Check my answer if you're looking for an explanation of what the use of the `replace()` function is used for in this example. In short: it selects every instance of each character specified in the brackets (aeou) within that string, and replaces them with the next function parameter.

Comment: I understand how arrow functions, replace() and regex work but I guess i'm not understanding what `replaceChars[matchFunc]` is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) accepts a second parameter that can either be a string that each matched occurrence is replaced with, or a function that is called with the match for each match, whose return value is used to replace that match.

In your example, the `replaceChars` object provides the replacement for each character that could be matched.

This may make it more clear:

```js
var y = "abceOou".split("").reverse().join("");
var replaceChars={ "a": 0 , "e": 6, "o": 2, "u": 9 };
var t = y.replace(/[aeou]/g,match=>{
   console.log(`Replacing ${match} with ${replaceChars[match]}`);
  return replaceChars[match];
});
console.log(t)
```

Comment: I get it now. The regex invokes the function for each letter and the parameter of the function becomes "a", which returns replaceChars["a"], which equals 0. Thanks.

Comment: @JJ.M My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

This part is called an arrow function and it is defined like so:

```
arguments => 
{ 
  block of code
}
```

Arrow functions were added in ES6 and you can use them as callback functions (instead of using a standard anonymous function). In this particular example, when a character is part of the regular expression, then the arrow function executes that replaces is by the equivalent number in the object replaceChars.

Answer (score 0):

The `/g` is a regular expression that selects every instance of each character within "aeou" (instead of only selecting the first occurrence of "aeou") and replaces them with the value of `matchFunc => replaceChars[matchFunc]`.

For example, without `/g`:

```js
var string = "123 example 123 string 123";
string.replace("123", "Test"); // Replaces first instance of string "123"
```

Would print: "Test example 123 string 123"

And with `/g`:

```js
var string = "123 example 123 string 123";
string.replace(/[123]/g, "Test"); // Replaces every separate character with 1, 2 or 3.
```

Would print: "TestTestTest example TestTestTest string TestTestTest"

This is because it selects every instance of "1", "2" and "3", and replaces it with "Test".

Answer (score 0):

First off, your question is a little confusing, so next time try proof-reading your question before posting.

Let's say you have the function

```
const replaceChars={ "a": 0 , "e": 6, "o": 2, "u": 9 };
const replace = letter => replaceChars[letter]
```

(I changed the variable name for clarity). This is the same as

```
var replaceChars={ "a": 0 , "e": 6, "o": 2, "u": 9 };
function replace(letter) { 
  return replaceChars[letter] 
}
```

but much more succinct.

Try calling either function in your console:

```
replace('a') // returns 0
replace('e') // returns 6
```

That function is called for each of the matched letters in `y.replace(...)`